# Grep and ignoring leading whitespace

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I've been working on a script to search for names of defines, and then grab the hex values for them and put them in the list. Once I have the list of names I'll attempt to search for "#define [name]" using -w to ensure exact match, and then awk '{ print $3 }' to grab the hex value.

However it works if the line is similar to

```
a.h:#define [name] 0x000
```

But it does NOT work if it is similar to

```
a.h:    #define [name] 0x000
```

How can I get around this? I have tried this

```
grep -nrw "\s*#define[[:space:]]*$p" . --include=*.h | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

I thought the `\s*` would ignore the leading whitespace before `#define` but it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This question would be ideal for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: your grep seems working perfectly to me. Grep finds both lines, awk prints the hexa codes. You could try to replace $3 to $NF however if that is the hexa value is the last field in those lines.
May I ask if this would run on linux or unix? In case of linux I may have a nice grep for you.

Comment: I am facing issues with some developers putting comments after the hex value as well as function_name() in the comments...

Comment: wrote my idea as answer, also corrected few of my mistakes..

Answer (score 1):

If it's the last element, you can always use

```
... | awk '{print $NF}'
```

You can also filter in awk as well

```
awk '/#define/{print $NF}'
```

This will print the second field after a match with "#define"

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<NF-1;i++) if($i~"#define") print $(i+2)}'
```

Comment: you have to enclose the pattern in `/`.  It works.  Please add sample of the inputs where you have problems with.

Comment: For the edited comment.  `print $NF` prints the last field, whereas `print $3` the third element.  awk has the structure of condition{action}, action is done when the condition is met, here a pattern match.

Comment: Sample is in OP. I can't use $NF since some developers add comments after the hex value. So if I can get `#define` to be the first element, then printing the third element will work

Comment: So, your sample input is not covering all cases you're interested in.  It will be more useful to everyone if you have better representation of your cases.

Comment: Really what I wanted to solve was grep adding the filename in front of `#define`. So in this case, where we can't be sure of comments after the define value, we just want to grab element 3 (since that holds true across the code I am working on)

Answer (score 1):

On linux this may work perfectly:

```
grep -Poinr "#define\s+\[.*?\K[0-9a-f]+x[0-9a-f]+" . --include=*.h
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` still matches the lines you want, but the whitespace between the line number and the `#define` makes it a separate `awk` field.

```
find -iname '*.[ch]' -exec sed -nse 's/.*\(#define\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)\(.*\)/\1: \2/p' {} +
```

Replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` with your `$p`, if you want to run this search over the full text for every symbol separately.  (It'd be faster to extract a list of all the defines once, and then search it.)

I used `sed -s` in case you want to add a sed command to print the line number.  You were using `grep -n` and then throwing away the line number with awk, so I figured maybe you were showing a cut-down example of how you really use the `grep` output.

You could also use GNU grep `-o` to print only the part of the line that matches your pattern.  Then instead of having your pattern match whitespace the grep output lines will always look like

```
number:#define ...
```

like your awk command is expecting.

Comment: Ah so based on what you and John said, I am mistaken in assuming it will always be $3... John pointed out that I could check $1 and $2 to be #define and name first, before print $3 which would be the desired value.

Comment: Yup.  Do you want to exclude commented-out `#define` lines?  Because I see you used `grep -w` instead of `^` to anchor your pattern to the start of the line.

Comment: yes but the -w was more for matching [name] exactly as is. Since there are various defines in the release like A, A_A and A_B. If I picked up A to begin with, I want A and not the other 2. how would I use the `^` differently?

Comment: @Gammerx:  You'd use `^\s*#define` to match only un-commented defines.  If you want to match even commented ones, make your pattern match at least one character of whitespace after the symbol.  Your code doesn't handle `#define foo\ ` with the definition on the next line anyway. I updated my answer with some working sed code, and a `grep -o` suggestion.

Comment: Right I only want the uncommented defines. I've added -o but since I have -w, it only gets `#define` and `name` but not the third element which is the hex value. Should I change my line to add something like `[[:space:]]*0x*` after the `$p` ?

Comment: Oh, yeah that would work.  Use `\s+0x[[:xdigit:]]+`.  `x*` matches zero-or-more literal `x`s.  Since you only want the uncommented defines, you do need to match all the way to the beginning of the line, so try `^\s+#define\s+$p\s+0x[[:xdigit:]]+`, without `-n`.  If you omit `-n`, then awk won't have the line number as a separate token.

Comment: This is now what I am using `grep -orw "#define\s*$p\s*0x\(.*\)"`
It avoids commented defines and picks up any hex values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this as our sample input:

```
$ cat a.h
other name 0x100
#define name 0x000
    #define name 0x001
```

#### Using awk

```
$ p=name; awk -v v="$p" '$1=="#define" && $2==v{print $3}' a.h
0x000
0x001
```

If we want to require that the printed value is a hex number:

```
$ p=name; awk -v v="$p" '$1=="#define" && $2==v && $3 ~ /^0x[[:xdigit:]]+$/{print $3}' a.h
0x000
0x001
```

#### Using sed

```
$ p=name; sed -nE "s/\s*#define\s+$p\s+([[:xdigit:]]*)/\1/p" a.h
0x000
0x001
```

If we want to be a bit more strict about what we match:

```
$ p=name; sed -nE "s/\s*#define\s+$p\s+(0x[[:xdigit:]]*)$/\1/p" a.h
0x000
0x001
```

### awk and leading spaces

The presence of leading spaces does not change how awk numbers a field:

```
$ echo '   1 2' | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "field %s = %s\n",i,$i;}'
field 1 = 1
field 2 = 2
$ echo '1 2' | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "field %s = %s\n",i,$i;}'
field 1 = 1
field 2 = 2
```

Comment: So - let me get this right - you are basically defining $1 and $2 to be #define and name respectively before printing $3 correct? And this would guarantee it being the hex value

Comment: @Gammerx _"defining $1 and $2 to be #define and name"_ To be clear, we do not  _define_ `$1` and `$2` to be `#define` and `name`, we test for equality before printing.  In awk, `==` is a test, not an assignment.  Separately, I updated the answer with versions that require the third value to be a hex number.

Comment: Right, it is to check equality. However, isn't adding spaces before `#define` shift the `#define` and `name` to $2 and $3 respectively?

Comment: @Gammerx No, it does not.  See the code I added to the end of the answer that demonstrates this.

Comment: @Gammerx By the way, I restricted the output to a specified name.  Did you want all defines with any name?

Comment: Well I also need it to be recursive. I need defines of any name from all headers both in the pwd and subdirs. I think I just got it, this seems to work:

    `grep -Ro '#define\s*\(.*\)' *.h`

Comment: @Gammerx That command is not "recursive" and it does not produce the output that you asked for in the question.

Comment: the R flag is recursive and gets pretty much everything I need. My final solution is: `grep -orw "#define\s*$p\s*0x\(.*\)" .  --include=*.h`

Comment: `grep -Ro '#define\s*\(.*\)' *.h` operates recursively _only_ in the unlikely even that directories have names ending with `.h`.  Otherwise, it ignores subdirectories and the files they contain.